# How add new locale on Jekyll?

Tags: plugins, jekyll, locale

There is jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin used in the project. I have "ru" and "en" locale: "ru" is default and opens in main page http://example.com; "en" opens in http://example.com/en.
http://example.com/ru doesn't exist, so I tried to add a separate locale for "ru" but failed.
I followed this documentation:
https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin

And this is my _config.yml:

```
title: example
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "https://example.by" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin
  - jekyll-sitemap

sass:
  style: compressed

permalink: /blog/:slug/

languages: ["ru", "en"]
exclude_from_localizations: ["javascript", "images", "css", "scripts", "favicons.ico"]
```

And my [scheme of locale files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNMx4.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out that this plugin does not create a separate locale for the default language (the default language in languages is indicated first, and in my case it is Russian).
If creating a separate locale is essential, then the answers are here:
https://github.com/kurtsson/jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin/issues/86